# Does fork & exit make a process a daemon?

Tags: daemon

```c
int main()
{
    if (!fork()) sleep(3000);
    exit(0);
}
```

Invoking the program above from the shell yields a orphan process which

1. is adopted by `init` or `upstart` (on my Ubuntu Desktop)
2. is in the same session as the shell
3. lost group leader
4. is not managed by the shell's job control, **which means it will not receive SIGHUP even if the shell receive an SIGHUP**

About 4: I have tested and confirmed this in `bash` on my Ubuntu Desktop. Not sure whether this hold true for signals other than SIGHUP. The same applies if you `disown` a job: process groups that are not listed by `jobs` command will not receive SIGHUP.

Since we can also close all FDs and `chdir`, and log to files, the only difference between this and a normal daemonization is that:

1. my process still shares the same session with the shell
2. my process still has a "controlling tty", as displayed by `ps j`

**So my problem is: Can we consider this process as a daemon?**

Or in other words, why it is so important for a daemon to be in a new session (call `setsid()`) without ctty, since it doesn't matter anything (correct me if not) for it to be in the same session of the calling shell with ctty connected?

Or in other words again: Why it is bad for a process who wants to serve as a daemon to keep its session unchanged and still connected to a terminal (even if we close its FDs)?

I think these problems are consistent in their nature. Thanks in advance.

#### References (yet didn't convince me)

- [Stack Overflow - What's the difference between nohup and a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon)
- [Stack Overflow - Linux daemonize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize)
- [Stack Overflow - What is the effect of leaving the call setsid() when creating daemon processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638616/what-is-the-effect-of-leaving-the-call-setsid-when-creating-daemon-processes)
- [Cause a process to become a daemon](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/cause_a_process_to_become_a_daemon.html)
- [Unix FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20120428044610/http://www.steve.org.uk:80/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC16)

Comment: The  `setsid()` question's accepted answer mentions quote from [external source](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/cause_a_process_to_become_a_daemon.html#idp2137): "When a user logs out from a session, all processes associated with that session are killed. For processes that are daemons you do not want this to happen." Your code example will be killed if either session or controlling tty exit, making it non-daemon. At least so is my understanding

Comment: Also relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240646/85039