# What does Session ID mean within the pkill context?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, command, pkill

About the `pkill` command, I know is possible kill processes  - for *specific scenarios* - based through `tty[1-6]` and `pts/[0-N]`. I tested and works as expected. Until here all is ok.

But now, according with this answer and solution:

- [What is the difference between kill , pkill and killall?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252360/383045)

it indicates (extraction):

> pkill and killall are also wrappers to the kill system call, (actually, to the libc library which directly invokes the system call), but can determine the PIDs for you, based on things like, process name, owner of the process, **session id**, etc.

Observe the *session id* part. I did do check both `man` and only exists this feature for `pkill` according with any of:

- [pkill from commandlinux.com](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/pkill.1.html)
- [pkill from linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

as follows respectively:

```
-s sid,...
Only match processes whose process session ID is listed. 
Session ID 0 is translated into pgrep's or pkill's own session ID.

-s, --session sid,...
Only match processes whose process session ID is listed. 
Session ID 0 is translated into pgrep's or pkill's own session ID.
```

As you can see the content is the same with a minor variation in the options/parameters names.

If I use:

- directly the console, therefore is possible use `pkill` based on `tty[1-6]` to kill something
- a remote connection through `ssh`, therefore is possible use `pkill` based on `pts/[0-N]` to kill something.

The reason of this post:

**Question**

- What does *Session ID* mean within the `pkill` context?

**Extra Questions**

- How was a *Session ID* created?
- How to know/retrieve a list of *Sessions ID* to be used for `pkill`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session id is the identifier of a process’ session. Sessions are a concept tied to shell job control, at a level above process groups; all processes in a given session share the same controlling terminal. In non-graphical environments, sessions can be thought of as login sessions (at least, that’s part of the original idea; they mustn’t be confused with systemd sessions which track login sessions in systemd-based environments).

Sessions are created with a call to [`setsid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html); see also [their description in `man credentials`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). Those links are to Linux-specific documentation, but this isn’t Linux-specific; see also [the POSIX specification for `setsid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html).

`ps` can show session ids:

```
ps -eo pid,sess,args
```

Comment: I assumed it was a special kind of connection, something "similar" than `tty/pst`, but since you did mention of the `setsid` method - it seems it is accomplish manually. Am I correct?

Comment: Why would be mandatory or need it use the `setid` method?

Comment: I’m not sure what you have in mind with `tty/pst` (`tty/pts`?). Processes which care about terminals will take care of `pts` etc., and processes which care about sessions might need to call `setsid`. One common reason to call `setsid` is to ensure that the process has its own controlling terminal (or none at all), so that it doesn’t get a `SIGHUP` related to something else closing; see [Why we use setsid() while daemonizing a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240646/86440) for example.